Code coverage for Attributes with dotCover and C#
We use dotCover (by Jetbrains). We have some custom attributes on properties of models and dotCover shows they are not covered by tests. I tried a number of ways to make tests for them but dotCover still shows that they are not covered.
Does someone know how to make the tests so that dotCover takes them into account?

"I tried a number of ways to make tests for them" - Is there actually anything to test about them? Or would it be more beneicial to just exclude them from being accounted in dotCover? I don't see how adding BS Tests just to please a tool would improve anything. => https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Reference_Options_dotCover_Filtering.html
